# laravel queue in multi servers

Tags: laravel, architecture, queue, jobs

I am going to make UGC project. I have a Main Server (Application) & 4 Encoder Servers (fro converting videos) and a Storage server (for hosting videos).
I want to use database driver in laravel queue and my target database is jobs. for each uploaded videos I have 5 certain jobs that convert video to 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p & and 1080p.
but jobs Does not specify belongs to which Encoder servers. for example a video uploaded in Encoder Server #4 , but Encoder Server #2 try to start job and get failed because files are in Encoder Server #4
how can I solve this chanlenge?

Comment: I didn't get the whole idea, but I guess you are trying implement micro services architecture. If yes, you could communicate with different databases using different `connections` in `config\database.php`.

Comment: Upload files to some sort of shared storage (like e.g. S3) to take full advantage of a multi-server environment

Answer (score 0):

As @apokryfos says, upload the file to a shared storage like Amazon S3 / Google Cloud Storage/ Digital Ocean spaces) .. whatever..

Have the processing job download it from a central store, process it, and upload the result to another central storage.

If you bind a single job to a single worker, (encoder server) as you call it,
It does not make any sense, and it will never be scalable, and are pretty much doomed, to run into issues.

Doing it this way, you can just scale up the number of workers, once you need it.
you could even auto scale them.

Consider using a kubernetes deployment, to allow easy (auto) scaling.